# Aggregate Iterable values with Spark API

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I'm experimenting Spark with Java 8 to do some analysis on a CSV file.

I want to compute a sum of elements by key.

My RDD is of type `JavaPairRDD<String, Iterable<Record>>` and I want to transform this RDD to `JavaPairRDD<String, Integer>` where the integer value is the sum of all elements in the iterable collection.

Record is a simple java POJO.

Any idea on how to do this ?

```
    JavaPairRDD<String, Iterable<Record>> distinct = map
    .filter(record -> record.circonference > 170)
    .groupBy(record -> record.espece)
    .distinct();
```

My POJO class

```
    public static class Record implements Serializable {

    private String geoPoint;
    private float circonference;
    private String addresse;
    private float hauteur;
    private String espece;
    private String variete;
    private String datePlantation;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your input RDD is called rdd,

```
rdd.mapValues(records -> {
  Integer ret = 0;
  for(Record r: records) {
      ret += Math.round(ret.circonference);
      ret += Math.round(ret.hauteur);
  }
  return ret;
})
```

I'm not really sure why you would want to sum all of the floats into an integer, but this should more or less do the trick for you. `mapValues` allows us to apply a function to the values part of a key/value pair while keeping the same key so its a good fit for this type of problem.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by myself using mapToPair transformation.

We can map the second element with the size of the iterable collection like this :

```
    JavaPairRDD<String, Iterable<Record>> distinct = map
    .filter(record -> record.circonference > 170)
    .groupBy(record -> record.espece)
    .mapToPair(t -> new Tuple2<String,Integer>(t._1, Lists.newArrayList(t._2).size()))
```